# Перегрузка оператора [] C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

У меня есть односвязный список. В нем надо перегрузить [] так, чтоб был доступ к элементу в заданной позиции. Но у меня, что-то не очень выходит.
Код:

```
List List::operator[](int n) {
    this->getElem(n);
    return *this;
}
```

getElem - метод поиска элемента в списке:

```
elem* List::getElem(int pos) { //рабочая.
elem *temp = head;
if (pos < 1 || pos > coun) {
    cout << "\nНеверная позиция!";
}
int i = 1;
while (i < pos && temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
    i++;
}
if (temp == NULL)
    return 0;
else
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: *доступ к элементу в заданной позиции* - тогда зачем возвращаете `List`?

Comment: Логично предположить, что `operator[]` должен возвращать элемент, а не список. Вам нужно возвращать то, что вернет `getElem(n)`

Comment: @acade Так а как мне выловить это? Я новый в этом деле. this->getElem(n); тут я получил этот элемент, а дальше как мне его вернуть, а не List?

Comment: `return this->getElem(n)` в `operator[]`, а также изменить тип возвращаемого значения `operator[]` c `List` на `elem*`

Comment: @acade Спасибо большое!!! А еще вопрос. При команде cout << T[1]; выводит адрес элемента, а не данные,как это исправить?

Comment: Разыменовать полученный указатель: `std::cout << *T[1];`

Comment: @acade Я так делал, но компилятор ругается: 
бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "elem" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: Нужно либо перегрузить оператор вывода для `elem`, либо выводить конкретное поле `elem`, например `std::cout << T[1]->value` если `elem` содержит поле `value`

Comment: @acade Все, понял. Спасибо еще раз большое!